After his ’74 Chevy Nova there had been his all-terrain four-wheel-drive Blaze
James Hetfield, meanwhile, was involved in less cerebral pursuits but
more challenging emotional issues. In common with both Lars and Kirk, his
longstanding relationship – with Kristen, subject of ‘Nothing Else Matters’
– had not been able to survive the ravages of the three-year Black tour. His
way of dealing with it was not to seek out new pleasures, or more esoteric
forms of self-expression, but to re-immerse himself in some of the old
ways. When he wasn’t drinking beer, watching the Oakland Raiders, he was
working in his garage, customising cars and motorcycles. After his ’74
Chevy Nova there had been his all-terrain four-wheel-drive Blaze, which he
nicknamed The Beast. He was also building himself an impressive
collection of vintage guitars, with special emphasis on those from 1963, the
year of his birth.
""Enter night" by Mick Wall
After his ’74 Chevy Nova there had been his all-terrain four-wheel-drive Blaze, which he nicknamed The Beast-Could you please explain the use of Past Perfect? What does it precede?

He was also building himself an impressive collection of vintage guitars is doubtful.

Why the Past Perfect? It suggests that Blaze was before the time being spoken of.

The Past Perfect here is a highly context-specific stylistic choice, that you should probably never think of imitating as a non-native speaker. In any remotely similar context in an exam, you'd always be expected to write After his ’74 Chevy Nova there was his all-terrain four-wheel-drive Blaze. The stylistic device occurs within the context of a biography (of a heavy metal band that's been around for over half a century, would you believe! :). The effect of the Perfect there is to make that "history" seem even longer (the Blaze "precedes" even "the end of the past history".

There is a narrative here.  There is a "narrative time"  In this case the narrative time is the time after the tour, when he is building a collection of guitars.
A that time the Chevy Nova and the Blaze were completed.  If you asked him he would have said "I have customised a ’74 Chevy Nova and there has been my all-terrain four-wheel-drive Blaze, which I call The Beast".  Since at the time he would have used a perfect aspect, when you report his you must use past perfect.

The past perfect there presents his all-terrain Blaze as one distraction in a series of distractions.  He was "dealing with" the relationship's emotional issues by "working in his garage, customising cars and motorcycles". The implication is that other customization projects, though not specifically mentioned, followed after the Blaze. The Blaze was not the culmination.
